# Can't reset BackInTime snapshot path

Tags: backup, backintime

I've been using BackInTime with Ubuntu 12.04.  The disk I was saving to is no longer available.  BackInTime insists that I bring it back.  (It says "Can't find snapshots folder.  If it is on a removable drive please plug it and then press OK")

No matter what I've tried, I can't seem to get beyond this point.  I've even tried removing BackInTime and re-installing it.  The problem persists.

How can I change the snapshots path without the missing disk?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to manually edit BackInTime's config file for your new snapshot location. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gedit .config/backintime/config`

Change the line `profile1.snapshots.path=/old/path` into `profile1.snapshots.path=/new/path`. Save and exit. You have to move the old backintime folder to that location before starting BackInTime.

Alternative if you lost all your previous snapshots and just want to start new you can remove the config by press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `rm .config/backintime/config`

Answer (score 0):

Adding usb disk with appropriate snapshot path doesn't work for me at all. I expect the backup to occur when I put the disk in, but I just get the: "Back in Time () : Main Profile. Can't find snapshots folder. If it is on a removable drive, please plug it in. Waiting 30 seconds".

Eventually I'd like to switch on an integral HDD like this guy does for Windows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BZnljKjJLvM

Here's path profile:

profile1.snapshots.path=/media/ian/usbBackup
profile1.snapshots.path.host=Adders06
profile1.snapshots.path.profile=1
profile1.snapshots.path.user=ian
profile1.snapshots.path.uuid=34cd9f80-4370-4659-b6c6-ec2dce789efc