# Backintime cannot find my snapshots

Tags: backup, restore, backintime

My Hard Drive failed and I had to do a fresh install of Ubuntu (13.10). Fortunately (maybe) I had backed up most of the folders from /etc and /home using Backintime (root). I installed BIT on the new system. The BIT information was stored in a separate HD, with the same path as was used for the original backup.  I copied the config file from the last snapshot:  /Backup/backintime/{old host name}/root/1/{latest backup folder} to ~/.config/backintime/.

When I try to use BIT it cannot find my snapshots. I looked at the config file following the hint given here:

[Can't reset BackInTime snapshot path](https://askubuntu.com/questions/183743/cant-reset-backintime-snapshot-path)

However, the path is correct so I did not have to change it there.

The hostname on the new system is different than the old machine, could this cause a problem?

Is there any other way to restore the files, even if to a different directory? If so, how? Is there something else I need to change somewhere?

Comment: Well, I found that I could copy many of the files and folders from the backintime files to my home directory (it said that it could not copy some of them).  I guess the one folder that did not get backed up properly was ~/.thunderbird. It had backed up the settings and the crash reports but not the actual E-Mail or Contacts. I don't know why that would be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to recover the files (I still could not use the Restore function of BIT). I found that the problem with recovering my .thunderbird folder was caused by the permissions (owner: root and read-only).  Once that was fixed, I was able to recover that. It was not as critical to me, but I was also able to recover my .mozilla folder by fixing the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

#### BackInTime version < `1.1.0`

You have to deactivate `Auto Host / User / Profile ID` and change the value for `Host` to match your old systems hostname. After that all snapshots should be shown in the main window.

#### BackInTime version >= `1.1.0`

On first start BackInTime will ask if you would like to restore your old config. Maybe connect your external drive and click `Yes`. It will scan your drives and collaps all folders with snapshots. Just select the snapshot from which you would like to restore the config and click `Restore`.

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm member of BIT-Dev Team</sub>